# Dual notion of the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, universal-property

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets with $\iota:X\to Y$ an injection. If $Y$ is a topological space, we define the subspace topology on $X$ as the initial topology induced by this diagram.

Analogously, if $X$ is a topological space, we can consider the final topology induced on $Y$. Does this topology have a name, and does it have any interesting properties? My intuition completely shuts down when I try to think about this object.

I should probably mention, this question occurred to me when I was looking for a "power set topology"

Thanks!

Comment: If $X\rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map, then this topology is known as the quotient topology, I think.

Comment: Right, for a projection this is standard. But what about the case of an injection?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the definition.

$U \subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq X$ is open. If $f$ isn't surjective (don't use the word projection), then let $y \in Y$ not in $f(X)$.

Then $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = \varnothing \subseteq X$ which is open.
Therefore you get the quotient topology on $f(X)$ and the discrete topology on its complement.

Comment: In particular, since $\iota$ is an injection, we identify $X$ as a subset of $Y.$ Then a subset $U\subset Y$ is open if and only if $\iota^{-1}(U)$ is open, i.e. if and only if $U\cap X$ is open in $X.$

Comment: Typo : it should be $f^{-1}(\{y\})$.